# How to fix a linker error with PKEY_Device_FriendlyName

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2005

Upon using PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PKEY_Device_FriendlyName DefaultAudioDeviceCPP.obj   
Error   2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\srobertson\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\DefaultAudioDeviceCPP\Debug\DefaultAudioDeviceCPP.exe
```

What's a very simple way to clear these errors?  I'm including functiondiscovery.h and functiondiscoverykeys.h.  Also the path in Project->Properties...->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories is correct.

EDIT: One thing of interest is that the errors are mentioning: _PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, not PKEY_Device_FriendlyName.  But I'm only using the latter in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PKEY_Device_FriendlyName` resides in `uuid.lib` library. So you need to add a line to your source code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib")
```

Most often, you can check with MSDN which library you need to reference.

Comment: I've tried adding it, but I'm getting kind of the same errors.

Comment: Other than that, you might be using old version of Windows SDK, which does not yet have this symbol.

Comment: At least 6.1 and 7.0 have this symbol. BTW Visual Studio 2005 is not supported/compatible by these latest SDK versions which makes me suspect you have them installed, but they are not used by compiler/linker.

Comment: do you by any chance also know which lib PKEY_AudioEndpoint_Disable_SysFx resides in?

Comment: @serup I don't think it's in .lib but it's defined as GUID in such way that <initguid.h> (see another answer here) should help.

Answer (score 16):

Old post, but hopefully this answer will save someone some time.

I was having the same problem with DEVPKEY properties - like DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName. I got a very similar link error. I stumbled upon the answer in comments here:
[Referencing GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980920/referencing-guids)

Basically, add an #include  before the include for things like devpkey.h where the property keys are defined.

So, at the top of my file I have:

```
#include <setupapi.h>  
#include <initguid.h>  // Put this in to get rid of linker errors.  
#include <devpkey.h>  // Property keys defined here are now defined inline.
```

Answer (score 3):

An updated solution that worked for me, as per the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/pkey-device-friendlyname)

```
#include <functiondiscoverykeys.h>
```

Comment: It looks to have been updated to <functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h>, which solved it for me.