# Encountered an issue using MediaFoundation

Tags: video-capture, ms-media-foundation

My project is using MediaFoundation's Source Reader to capture and preview cameras, but I encountered the following issues when presenting videos using EVR.

Code:

```
#include <evr.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "evr.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
...
IMFGetService *pGetService = NULL; 
IMFVideoDisplayControl* pVideoDisplayControl = nullptr; 
pGetService->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, IID_IMFVideoDisplayControl, (void**)&pVideoDisplayControl);
...
```

Error:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol IID_IMFVideoDisplayControl
```

How to solve this problem？

This problem has been studied for 2 days but has not been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add

```
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
```

You can see it documented in any method of the `IMFVideoDisplayControl` interface (alas not on the interface itself...), for example [IMFVideoDisplayControl::GetVideoPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/evr/nf-evr-imfvideodisplaycontrol-getvideoposition#requirements)

[image]

This will fix the `MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE` issue too, although for this one (but not for the interface) you could have added the famous `<initguid.h>` see this [Referencing GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980920/referencing-guids)

I don't know how many human cycles have been lost on these....

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The problem has been solved. It looks like this is my problem, maybe I can find it just by going into a sub-option, but I didn't, thanks again.