# Using DXVA2 in MediaFoundation, LNK2001 was encountered when compiling

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I am using MediaFoundation to achieve camera capture. Since my camera supports H264 preview, I follow the instructions of the official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supporting-dxva-2-0-in-media-foundation to use DXVA2.0 in MediaFoundation. The following is part of my code. When compiling and linking, an error message of LNK2001 unresolved external symbol DXVA2_ModeH264_E appears. How can I solve it?

```
#include <evr.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <ks.h>
#include <ksproxy.h>
#include <Vidcap.h>
#include <Ksmedia.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <dxva2api.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "evr.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxva2.lib")
....
HANDLE pDeviceHandle = nullptr;
hr = pD3DManager->OpenDeviceHandle(&pDeviceHandle);
if (hr != S_OK)
    return -1;
IDirectXVideoDecoderService *pDirectXVideoDecoderService = nullptr;
hr = pD3DManager->GetVideoService(pDeviceHandle,  IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDirectXVideoDecoderService));
if (hr != S_OK)
    return -1;
UINT guidCount = 0;
GUID *pGUIDs = nullptr;
hr = pDirectXVideoDecoderService->GetDecoderDeviceGuids(&guidCount, &pGUIDs);
if (hr != S_OK)
    return -1;
GUID guid;
for (UINT i = 0; i < guidCount; ++i)
{
    if (pGUIDs != nullptr)
    {
        guid = pGUIDs[i];
        // DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_Stereo_Progressive_NoFGT
        // DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_Stereo_NoFGT
        // DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT
        if (IsEqualGUID(guid, DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT))
            break;
    }
}
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol DXVA2_ModeH264_E DDemo   D:\RHCTProject\VisualStudioPro\DDemo\mediacapture.obj   1       

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  DDemo   D:\RHCTProject\VisualStudioPro\DDemo\x64\Debug\DDemo.exe    1
```

Comment: Add `#include <initguid.h>` at the beginning of the file with entry point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referencing GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980920/referencing-guids)

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks for your reply, this solved my problem. May I ask why I can use it normally after adding #include<initguide.h>.
In Visual Studio 2022, I can jump to the DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT(DXVA2_ModeH264_E) definition.