# [windows wasapi, visual studio 2017 c++ project]cannot resolve symbol PKEY_AudioEndpoint_FormFactor

Tags: windows, wasapi

When I use Windows WASAPI to get the audio device properties, 
the following 3 properties compiled good,

- PKEY_Device_FriendlyName
- PKEY_Device_DeviceDesc
- PKEY_DeviceInterface_FriendlyName

but when I use PKEY_AudioEndpoint_FormFactor, the Visual Studio 2017 prompts the following error
**error LINK2001**
"cannot resolve symbol **PKEY_AudioEndpoint_FormFactor**"

Can anyone help what lib is missed for **PKEY_AudioEndpoint_FormFactor** in the link setting of visual studio project?

Comment: When I added #include <initguid.h>, it compiled Good.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42236266/17034

Comment: @Hans Passant, Thanks.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/00853e55-51dd-46bc-bceb-04c0c2e5cc06/unresolved-external-symbols?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment

Try to include #include <initguid.h> (it must be the first include)